# preint and postrm scripts are not running showing as access denied

Tags: apt, perl

```
root@XXXXXXXXXX:/home/user# apt install /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.36.0-7                                                                                     ubuntu0.23.04.2_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'perl' instead of '/var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.36.0-7ubuntu0.23.                                                                                     04.2_amd64.deb'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  perl-base
Suggested packages:
  perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl
  libtap-harness-archive-perl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  perl perl-base
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,020 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 116068 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../perl_5.36.0-7ubuntu0.23.04.2_amd64.deb ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new perl package pre-installation script (/var                                                                                     /lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst): Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.36.0-7ubuntu0.23.04.2                                                                                     _amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new perl package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new perl package post-removal script (/var/lib                                                                                     /dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm): Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 new perl package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../perl-base_5.36.0-7ubuntu0.23.04.2_amd64.deb ...
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new perl-base package pre-installation script                                                                                      (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst): Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.36.0-7ubuntu0.23                                                                                     .04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new perl-base package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit statu                                                                                     s 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new perl-base package post-removal script (/va                                                                                     r/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm): Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 new perl-base package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.36.0-7ubuntu0.23.04.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.36.0-7ubuntu0.23.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Getting above error any installation or upgrade of ubuntu server.

Comment: Why are you trying to install perl with apt from a cached file? What are you trying to do exactly? Can you re-post the terminal output without line truncation?

Comment: i need to install libnghttp2 , for that also it is showing same message :
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new perl package pre-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst): Permission denied

Comment: root@XXX:/etc/apt/apt.conf.d# apt install libnghttp2-14
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  perl perl-base
Suggested packages:
  perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl libtap-harness-archive-perl
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnghttp2-14 perl perl-base
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.

Comment: dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new perl package pre-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst): Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.36.0-7ubuntu0.23.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new perl package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new perl package post-removal script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm): Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 new perl package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../perl-base_***.deb

Comment: dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new perl-base package pre-installation script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst): Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.36.0-7ubuntu0.23.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new perl-base package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute new perl-base package post-removal script (/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/postrm): Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 new perl-base package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/perl_5.36.0-7ubuntu0.23.04.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/perl-base_5.36.0-7ubuntu0.23.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Issue got resolved by removing "nosuid,noexec,nodev" mount options from /etc/fstab. as we added these noexec option in mount, mentioned scripts are getting permission denied. After removing those and rebooted the server, i am able to install any package or do apt upgrade. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got resolved by removing "nosuid,noexec,nodev" mount options from /etc/fstab. as we added these noexec option in mount, mentioned scripts are getting permission denied. After removing those and rebooted the server, i am able to install any package or do apt upgrade. Thanks for the support.